# Why can't I use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA in a sub-select?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to prune a table in a database using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. To test the DELETE I am using a SELECT to see if the data is coming back correctly. I want to delete the data from `master.company` based on whether or not the database exists. This is what I have tried and it doesn't work:

```
USE DATABASE master;

CREATE TABLE `company` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `db_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `domain` (`domain`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

SELECT db_name FROM master.company WHERE db_name IN (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA);
```

However, I can get it to work when I reverse reference the tables like so:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME in ( SELECT db_name FROM master.company);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Both your `select` statements should yield correct results. Take a `db_name` that appears from your successful query (2nd one) and try to execute the first one like so: `select...where db_name in ('<value>')`. Second try is to cast both schema_name and db_name to varchar(255) and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [10.1.7.9 Collation and INFORMATION_SCHEMA Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collation-information-schema.html).

Try:

```sql
SELECT `c`.`db_name`
FROM `company` `c`
  INNER JOIN `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA` `iss`
  ON `c`.`db_name` = `iss`.`SCHEMA_NAME`;
```

**UPDATE 1**

It really looks more like a bug with the IN clause.

See <kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a259/1)</kbd>

Try the following [13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```sql
SET @`qry` := CONCAT('
SELECT
  `id`,
  `domain`,
  `name`,
  `db_name`
FROM `company`
WHERE `db_name` IN (',
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('\'', `SCHEMA_NAME`, '\''))
       FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA`),
')');
PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`qry`;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/623fb/2)</kbd>

Remember to set the variable correctly: [`group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).

**UPDATE 2**

The problem does not occur in earlier versions to MySQL 5.6:

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo MySQL 5.6](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a259/23)</kbd>
<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo MySQL 5.5](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a259/1)</kbd>

Bug reported: [Bug #77191 Subquery on information_schema including an IN clause, does not return results](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77191)

**UPDATE 3**

Workaround:

```sql
SET @@session.optimizer_switch := 'semijoin=off';
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo MySQL 5.6](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a259/25)</kbd>

Comment: UPDATE 3 was the one that worked for what I needed. I was able to set the optimizer_switch and run my query as expected. Thanks!